# Regular Expression to Match Lines Ending with Comma - TextMate

Tags: regex, textmate

I have multiple lines such as:

```
a,b,c,10
d,e,f,
g,h,i,19
l,m,n,
o,p,q,21
```

I need a regular expression that will match all lines that end with a comma. So the second and fourth lines. It should work for any line, not just the ones above.
I am using a text editor to find such lines, in this case TextMate.

Thank you.

Comment: Search for `/,$/` in `MULTILINE` mode

Comment: Please specify which language or tool you are using as well, so we can give more precise answers.

Comment: Not really a textmate question

Answer (score 2):

```
/,$/
```

`,` is the comma and `$` means end of line. In other words, a comma next to the end of line.